# Access current user's id in drupal views filter creteria

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I'm trying to filter content based on the current user's id. Is this possible using Drupal Views?

Thank you very much :)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show a list of content that is authored by the logged-in user, do the following:

1. Add a new Contextual Filter
2. Select 'Content: Author uid'
3. Select the 'Provide default value'-option
4. Select 'User ID from logged in user' from the dropdown

Hope this helps.